# Non type template parameter in msvc does not compile

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, function-templates

I studied about non-type template parameter and came to know that they must be compile time constant. Then I created the below given program that compiles with gcc as well as clang but fails to compile with msvc. I am working with c++20 and want to know which compiler is correct here.

```
struct C 
{

};
template<C c> int func() {
    return 5;
}

int main() {
    C a{};
    func<a>();   //compiles in gcc and clang but fails in msvc
    
}
```

[See demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/3qz1zxxnx)

MSVC says:

```
example.cpp
<source>(11): error C2672: 'func': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(5): note: could be 'int func(void)'
<source>(11): note: 'func': template parameter 'c': 'a': a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument
<source>(10): note: see declaration of 'a'
Compiler returned: 2
```

Comment: This bug is fixed in MSVC v19.37. Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/GMebnofzb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[temp.arg.nontype]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.arg.nontype#2):

> A *template-argument* for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression of the type of the template-parameter.

[[expr.const]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#10):

> A *converted constant expression* of type `T` is an expression, implicitly converted to type `T`, where the converted expression is a constant expression and [...]

(The omitted part is not relevant to this case.)

It should be clear that `a` can be [implicitly converted](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.general#3) to its own type. Such a conversion makes use of `C`'s implicitly-declared copy constructor, which is `constexpr`, has a single parameter of type `const C&`, and performs no action (since the class is empty) ([[class.copy.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.copy.ctor#6)).

Binding a reference to `a` does not prevent an expression from being a core constant expression ([[expr.const]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5)), despite the fact that `a` has automatic storage duration and is not `constexpr`. A value of an empty class type also trivially satisfies the constraints imposed by [[expr.const]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#11).

Thus, `a` in `func<a>` *is* a converted constant expression, even though `a` by itself is not a constant expression.

---

So yes, this is an MSVC bug. And it seems to be specific to NTTPs, because this similar program is rightfully accepted:

```cpp
struct C {};

int main() {
    C a;
    constexpr C b = a;
}
```