# Class template partial specialization for const and not-const pointers

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, partial-specialization, non-type-template-parameter

I am trying to make a class template with non-type template parameter of pointer type, which has two specializations for const and not-const pointers.

This is my best attempt, accepted by Clang and GCC:

```
template <const int*>
struct A {};

template <int* p>
struct A<p>;

int v;
A<&v> a;
```

but `A<&v>` still uses the primary template with const pointer despite `&v` has type `int*`.

On the other hand, MSVC prints:

```
error C2753: 'A<p>': partial specialization cannot match argument list for primary template
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/EzoYoxEza

Is my partial specialization correct? And if yes, how can I use `A<int*>`?

---

Another attempt was to declare the primary template with `auto` non-type template parameter and specialize it twice:

```
template <auto>
struct A;

template <int* p>
struct A<p> {};

template <const int* p>
struct A<p>;

int v;
A<&v> a;
```

It works fine with GCC, but both Clang and MSVC complain:

```
Clang error: ambiguous partial specializations of 'A<&v>'
MSVC error C2752: 'A<&v>': more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/43bj6EWq6

Considering that all compilers agreed in the previous example that `template <int* p>` is more specialized than `template <const int* p>`, which one is correct here?

Comment: A variation is only accepted by gcc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TaYT7fvcv). this one is accepted [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4n7hcKcqn), but msvc doesn't support const pointer in that version [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4n7hcKcqn).

Comment: For me this does not look like a specialization at all. `A<p>` syntax implies that `int*` matches `const int*`. ¿Or is this some sort of change in C++20?

Comment: Did you forget to add `language-lawyer` tag?

Comment: @user12002570, thanks. I have added `language-lawyer` tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, this is an MSVC bug. In C++20, there is a relatively elegant workaround:

```cpp
template <auto>
struct A;

template <auto p>
  requires std::same_as<decltype(p), const int*>
struct A<p> { };

template <auto p>
  requires std::same_as<decltype(p), int*>
struct A<p> { };
```

MSVC does correctly select the `const int*` and `int*` specializations in this case; see [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/G3fK179oE).

Note that this solution currently does not work with GCC due to a memoization bug ([**Bug 113274**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113274)), so you may have to resort to something else entirely.

You could also use `#ifdef __GNUC__` to use your original version for anything but MSVC, and use this version just for MSVC.
This solution would be absolutely disgusting and insane, but seems to be the only way to keep the template parameter list clean for all compilers.

Comment: Thanks. But it looks that GCC has problems with this approach as well: https://godbolt.org/z/5Pqx6TG3W

Comment: @Fedor lmao. I guess you could use `#ifdef` between your original and my fix. That way you'll choose the MSVC compiler bug when compiling with GCC and Clang, and the GCC compiler bug when compiling with MSVC. Commenting out the first `static_assert` fixes the problem by the way, so it looks like a memoization bug.

Comment: Why do you suggest `std::same_as` approach instead of simpler `template <int* p> struct A<p>`? GCC/Clang again diverge: https://godbolt.org/z/43bj6EWq6 Which on is correct?

Comment: @Fedor evidently, Clang and MSVC don't seam to treat that one correctly either. I don't think there's any approach that works for all, unless you pick your poison per compiler with `#ifdef`. I'd still prefer to make the cut at GCC/Clang vs. MSVC, so that GNU-style compilers behave the same at least.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in MSVC. You can use following workaround to compile it without errors:

```cpp
template <typename T, T>
struct A {};

template <int* p>
struct A<int*, p> {};

template <const int* p>
struct A<const int*, p> {};

int v;
A<int*, &v> a;
A<const int*, &v> b;
```

For more information on this bug you can visit: [Non type template parameter in msvc does not compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75831432/non-type-template-parameter-in-msvc-does-not-compile)

Comment: *"MSCV does not support the use of non-type template parameters with pointer types directly..."* **Where is the source?**

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-chooses-specialization-over-primary/10175880, I'm understanding it as so, but if it's not correct I should rephrase it, let me know.

Comment: That is a different bug in msvc. It is not related to pointers non type parameter

Comment: Alright, I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Please note that the bug from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75831432/non-type-template-parameter-in-msvc-does-not-compile has been already fixed in the latest version of MSVC.